# Random crashes on socket 939 motherboard

Tags: crash

I have an MSI K8NGM2-FID and it just randomly crashes. The motherboard is an old socket 939.

I've tested the hardware, and the culprit is either the CPU or the motherboard, which are the two hardware components I don't have spares to test on. It's not the graphics card, onboard and external, as both have been tested.

The CPU does not overheat. It stays around 30C - 35C.

It is not the RAM. It's been tested. and swapped with 4 different DIMMS, amounts brands.

It's also not the PSU. Both a 24-pin and 20-pin have been tested on this machine.

The crash will be during a transition during software, such as Windows XP's installation saving, pulling up a statistics graph during a game, starting a browser.

This isn't a software issue, there is no software indication, neither is there a blue screen of death.

After crashing, the computer power indicator will blink 3 seconds on, 2 seconds off, and the computer can't be restarted until the power cable is removed and there is no more power to sustain the blinking.

Which one is the likely culprit? The CPU or the motherboard?

Comment: Is there anything unseated or loose that you're aware of? Also, perhaps try another outlet to plug your PC into as that one may be faulty.

Comment: I've used multiple systems on this outlet, and in multiple houses. I'm not aware of anything loose, as it was all reseated a while ago. A 550 watt PSU was tested, as well as a 350 watt one.

Comment: Eh, the system is so old that you may as well just replace both the CPU and the motherboard.

Comment: If I could, I would've. I've barely reached the age to work, and the motherboard is `newer` than what I'm using now.

Comment: Check for any bulging or leaking capacitors, motherboards (and other components) from that period were equipped with bad capacitors that are known to fail prematurely. You can replace them yourself if you can handle a soldering iron. badcaps.net has pictures and lots of other info...

Comment: Would a motherboard even start with a bad capacitor?

Comment: Sometimes, yes. I had a similar issue with a socket-939 board myself.

Comment: Any capacitor that's not flat on top is a bad one, as well as leaking ones correct? On the board I don't see any majorly bulging capacitors, but maybe like 1mm away from being flat.

Comment: I'll also note that the problem was progressive, as it got worse and worse over time. The computer was originally functional.

Comment: Yes, the capacitors should be completely flat on top - if not, they're bad. You can get replacements from Digikey or Mouser (look for low-ESR caps, Panasonic FM series are the ones I use). Just make sure the capacitance and voltage is the same (you can go higher (not lower) on voltage if necessary, but the capacitance has to be correct).